# Nutiteq ViewLabel doesn't appear

Tags: label, polygon, android-custom-view, nutiteq

Could anyone tell me what I do wrong?

I can build and display Polygons on my GeometryLayer in `Nutiteq` but when I try to create a custom Label aka ViewLabel is not displayed, with `DefaultLabel` works fine.

I have a normal XML Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/farmName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/farmName"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:text="@string/area"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Code

```
//Setting Popup Label if we click the area
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)this.
getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
View labelView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_field, null);


TextView farmNameTV = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.farmName);
TextView areaTV = (TextView)labelView.findViewById(R.id.area);

farmNameTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
farmNameTV.setTextSize(13*scale);
farmNameTV.setText("Farm Name: "+name);

GeometricUtils geomUtils = new GeometricUtils();
double area = geomUtils.computeArea(coordinates);


areaTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
areaTV.setTextSize(13*scale);        
areaTV.setText("Area :"+String.valueOf(area));


labelView.layout(0, 0, 400, 300);




LabelStyle labelStyle = LabelStyle.builder().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE).
                               setEdgePadding((int) (12 * scale)).
                               setLinePadding((int) (6 * scale)).
                               setTitleFont(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.BOLD),
                                            16 * scale).
                               setTitleColor(Color.BLACK).
                               setTitleAlign(Align.CENTER).
                               setDescriptionFont(Typeface.create("Arial",  
                                                  Typeface.NORMAL),13 * scale).
                               setDescriptionColor(Color.BLACK).
                               setDescriptionAlign(Align.CENTER).
                               build();




Label fieldLabel = new ViewLabel(fieldname, labelView, new Handler(), labelStyle);


// Without holes!
Polygon pol = new Polygon(outerPoses, null, fieldLabel, polygonStyleSet, null);
geomLayer.add(pol);
```

I have tried to set the attributes of View in XML File, programmatically too as you can see but without success.

[Capture of my issue](http://i57.tinypic.com/mvrr51.png)

I have even tried to programm an Extension of MapListener just for my Layer with Polygons and there get data from

```
public void onVectorElementClicked(VectorElement vectorElement, double x, double y,    
                                   boolean longClick) {
    if (vectorElement.getLabel() != null) {   
        ViewLabel label = vectorElement.getLabel();
        ...
        And here we can get all of data of label
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the issue is that you do not *measure* your layout, see https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Use-View-for-Label. You should add before webView.layout()

```
webView.measure(400, 300);
```

Comment: Hi Jaak,thx, that was it! I can't yet vote but when I can I'll vote positive. Kind regards!

Comment: @bavarol You can, however, [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), which gives both of you [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Sorry, I thought, Accept was linked to upvoting him and I can't upvote yet. Thx

Comment: I don't understand why I got -3 just cause of ask a question.